# how can I Change view in semantic detail page

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

[My one page application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOOsl.png)
Hi , Experts ! I want to display an another view only in the semantic detail page
and don't change the master page !
any idea ?!

Comment: Do you intend to navigate to a new View in the detail section ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this simply with [Routing](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html). You will have three views(Base App view, Master & Detail). You will have to create a new View for your detail page (`Charts.view.xml`).

Add a target route in you [manifest.json](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f.html).

```json
{
    "sap.ui5":{
        //...
        "routing":{
        //...
            "routes":[
                {
                    "pattern":"",
                    "name":"master",
                    "target":[
                        "detail",
                        "master"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pattern":"Charts",
                    "name":"charts",
                    "target":[
                        "detail",
                        "charts"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "targets":{
                "master":{
                    //...
                },
                "charts":{
                    "viewName":"Charts",
                    "viewLevel":2,
                    "viewId":"charts",
                    "controlAggregation":"detailPages"
                },
                "detail":{
                    //...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And on a certain Event you can navigate to your new View with

```js
onSemanticButtonPress : function() {
    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("charts");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of Fragments to display the content.

Comment: and can i delete the old content and display the new ?

Comment: yes you can reuse the same fragment and change the aggregation of it.

Comment: Check out this link you might get an idea over it http://embed.plnkr.co/26vI0HWJAOadKpPPOQ27/